# Aprender o ABC, em linguagem C?

Tags: c, compilação, char, auto-incremento

Como faço nesse código, quando ele digitar uma letra lida pelo teclado com o scanf do tipo (char) ela se repetir até o Z?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char c;

    /*for (c= 'A'; c<='Z'; c++){
        printf("Letra =  %c\n", c);
    } */
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realize o `scanf` da letra, e suprima a inicialização do contador no `for`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char c;
    char limit;
    scanf("%c", &c);

    if(c >= 65 && c <= 90){
         limit = 'Z';
    }else{
         limit = 'z';
    }

    for (; c<=limit; c++){
        printf("Letra =  %c\n", c);
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Só funciona com letras maiúsculas. coloquei assim e travou for(; c<='Z' || 'z'; c++) {

Comment: Como faço o ||(ou) então no for para z e Z?

Comment: @user24857 Acho que você quis fazer `for(; c<='Z' || c<='z'; c++) {`. Seu `for` "travou" (entrou num loop infinito) porque a segunda condição do "ou" - `'z'` - é sempre verdadeira (pois é diferente de zero). Já `c <= 'z'` pode ou não ser verdadeiro. Só que se você fizer o código assim, ele vai imprimir outros caracteres que não são letras (pois entre os intervalos `a-z` e `A-Z` existem vários símbolos).